# NullReferenceException when adding to repository

Tags: c#, exception

I think I must be missing something which is staring me straight in the face.

Here is my code:

```
 var addToBasket = new AddToBasket                                                                         
            {
                RetailerId = retailerId,
                ProductId = productId,
                Price = price,
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                WidgetImpressionId = widgetImpressionId,
                Quantity = quantity,
                VisitStore = false
            };
            _addToBasketRepository.Add(addToBasket);
```

On the `Add` I'm getting a NullReferenceException

Except I've checked all the values and none of them are null:

In the Watch window in VS:

> addToBasket    {AddToBasket Id = 0, RetailerId = 80, ProductId = 6566, Price = 1.89, CreatedAt = 24/10/2013 15:57:37, WidgetImpressionId = 191489981, VisitStore = False}  WidgetData.AddToBasket

I know Id = 0 but  its an Id column which auto increments so I don't think that can be the problem.

Comment: And what about `_addToBasketRepository`?

Comment: _addToBasketRepository needs to be initialised to new List<AddToBasket>()

Comment: Did you initialize `_addToBasketRepository`?

Comment: @Basilevs re-edited. I think it's better now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only object that can possibly be null to throw such an exception is `_addToBasketRepository`

I think that's your culprit.  you haven't instantiated `_addToBasketRepository`

**Even if** other objects are null, they won't throw a `NullReferenceException` until you try to access a property or method of the object in question.

---

You can fix this by putting the following line before you use `_addToBasketRepository`

```
// assuming that it is indeed a List and not some other collection
_addToBasketRepository = new List<AddToBacket>()
```

Comment: completely right i was too busy looking at the code at the bottom forgetting i hadn t instantiated _addtobasketrepository thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized `_addToBasketRepository` before using Add method? Also it can be helpful if you can include the code of `AddToBasket` constructor.

Comment: Questions go to comments.